# SAML encrypted response - how to get the private key?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement an SP initiated web browser SAML SSO profile in JBOSS.

My application is the SP.

I understood that I need to create a certificate for my server and send it to the IDP in the metadata file.

I have used the Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services to install the certificate.

Now, when I get the SAML response from the IDP it is encrypted:

```
<saml:EncryptedAssertion> ...
    <ds:X509Certificate> ... 
        <xenc:CipherData> ... 
            <xenc:CipherValue> .. SOME ENCRYPTED VALUE ... </xenc:CipherValue>
```

Now, I understand that in order to get the decrypted value I need something like:

```
File keyStoreFile = new File(MY_KEY_STORE_FILE);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile),MY_PASSWORD));
```

The question is: what is it the key store file? How do I get it and what format should it have?
I found the following folder:

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Keys 
Which contains a system file with no extension. Is this the private key? How do I use it in the code?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you exported the certificate from AD. Is the file you found in the systemCertificates directory something you exported? Here's [how to export](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329.aspx) the cert with a private key.

This will create a PKCS 12 or PKCS 8 (DER) certificate you should be able to load in Java using `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")` or `KeyStore.getInstance("RSA")`. Once you have the keystore loaded, for XML encryption, you will need a `KeyInfo` object, created like this:

```
PrivateKeyEntry entry = ((PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(certAlias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password)));

KeyInfoFactory keyFactory = KeyInfoFactory.getInstance();

KeyInfo keyInfo = keyFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(keyFactory.newX509Data(Collections.singletonList(entry.getCertificate()))));
```